1D Wave Equation with Resonant Boundary Condition
The question is essentially how to find one particular solution of the following boundary-value problem:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2},\; y(0, t) = 0,\; y(L, t) = \cos\left( \frac{n_0 \pi ct}{L} \right)\; (n_0 \in \mathbb{N}).
$$
Physically, one could consider a string of length $L$ in tension such that waves traverse through it with speed $c$, holding one end stationary and vibrating the other end at a resonant frequency.
I tried and largely failed to find a particular solution, after which any initial condition could be incorporated using complementary solutions.
I know that no separable solution could exist (as no separable solution could satisfy both boundary conditions), and I would presume that resonance without damping would lead to a solution growing without bound (such as $t \cos t$).
However, despite my efforts, I couldn't find a solution.
Since I know that finding particular solutions requires much intuition, it would be extremely helpful if you could explain what kinds of thoughts went through your mind while finding a solution. Thanks.

Try $y(x,t)=f(x)cos(\frac{n_0\pi ct}{L})+g(x,t)$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(L)=1$ then $g(0,t)=0$ and $g(L,t)=0$. I am looking for a solution of an equation that has fixed boundary conditions. Hopefully you can find such an $f(x)$ (it will satisfy a differential equation) leaving you to find a separable solution for $g$

Hmm, looks like that won't quite do it. The function $f(x)$ satisfies the harmonic oscillator equation and the boundary conditions won't give anything consistent.

Assuming you have initial conditions, you could apply a Laplace transform, solve the resulting ODE in $x$, then transform back.

I believe the Laplace transform is given by $$
Y(x,s) = \frac{\kappa}{\kappa^2 + s^2} \frac{\sinh\frac{sx}{c}}{\sinh\frac{s}{c}},
$$ where $\kappa = \frac{n_0 \pi c}{L}$, but inverting it isn't proving fruitful

In order to simplify the calculations below, let's set $c=L=1$. Also, in order to work with homogeneous boundary conditions, let's define $u=y-x\cos(n_0\pi t)$. This transforms the original problem into
$$
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=n_0^2\pi^2x\cos(n_0\pi t), \qquad u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0. \tag{1}
$$
Now we can solve Eq. $(1)$ using the method of Fourier series. Let
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(t)\sin(n\pi x) \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
n_0^2\pi^2x\cos(n_0\pi t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n\cos(n_0\pi t)\sin(n\pi x), \tag{3}
$$
where
$$
f_n=2\int_0^1n_0^2\pi^2x\sin(n\pi x)\,dx=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n_0^2\pi}{n}. \tag{4}
$$
Plugging $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\ddot{a}_n(t)+n^2\pi^2a_n(t)]\sin(n\pi x)=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n\cos(n_0\pi t)\sin(n\pi x)
$$
$$
\implies \ddot{a}_n(t)+n^2\pi^2a_n(t)=f_n\cos(n_0\pi t). \tag{5}
$$
The solution to $(5)$ is
$$
a_n(t)=A_n\cos(n\pi t)+B_n\sin(n\pi t)+
\begin{cases}
\frac{f_n}{(n^2-n_0^2)\pi^2}\,\cos(n_0\pi t)&\text{if $n\neq n_0$,} \\
\frac{f_{n_0}}{2n_0\pi}\,t\sin(n_0\pi t)&\text{if $n=n_0$.}
\end{cases} \tag{6}
$$
Therefore, the general solution to the original problem (with $c=L=1$) is
$$
y(x,t)=x\cos(n_0\pi t)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(t)\sin(n\pi x), \tag{7}
$$
with $a_n(t)$ given by $(6)$; the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ in $(6)$ are fixed by the initial conditions $y(x,0)$ and $y_t(x,0)$, which were not specified, and the coefficients $f_n$ are defined in $(4)$.
